# Using Webpack module loader in browser - only via JS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, systemjs

*Now that Angular2-cli  has moved to Webpack , I guess I should too.*

With System.Js I could load the file itself (`system.js`) in browser via :

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.39/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
 <script>
     System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
 </script>
```

And I was able to load modules from other files without any help of tool/library. ( besides system.src.js).

**Question**

Replacing System.js -

Which JS file should I load now in `<script src='?'>` in order to be able to load modules like in System.js ? Is it even possible ? (without any background process which does the work for me).

In other simple words - If I wanted to make a [**PLNKR like this one**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBmwQv8ELHNlCgtQcnCu?p=preview)
 , Without System.js but with webpack , What should I change in the plnkr in order to do it ?

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Webpack is a tool that you run in your build/deployment step. It will search for all dependencies introduces with `require` composing those to one or multiple chunks. the result will be one entry point file and optional chunks, and then you will only include this entry point file to your `html`.

Comment: @t.niese  yes but apart from that it's also module loader like system js . Now the question is can i use that module loader via a js file just like i did with systemjs.

Comment: Webpack ist a module bundler, and requires a preprocessing step. SystemJs is a module loader that loads all the required files at runtime. In webpack you will mainly use the `const moduleA = require('moduleA')` syntax and `module.exports` to expose functionality. The one that might be similar to the the `System.import` syntax is the [import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/#dynamic-import)  for dynamic import or code splitting, but this is also something that requires a preprocessing step. Webpack will create an entrypoint file, which is the only file you add to your html.

Comment: @t.niese so the answer to my question is : "You can't" ?

Comment: If you ask if webpack can be a client side only drop in replacement  for SystemJS, then the answer would be that it is not possible. You either need some server side code that does the preprocessing on the fly (e.g. an express.js middleware) or you need to do the composing before deployment.